# Creating dynamic Lambda from Existing Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

i have an extension method that configures the filtering for telerik grid. it receives lambda expressions as parameter. is it possible to make new expressions from existing ones e.g

```
public static void ConfigureFiltering<T>(this HtmlHelper html, Configurator conf, params Expression<Func<T,object>>[] args) where T:class 
{
 }
```

i want to create expressions like

```
Expression<Func<object,bool?>> filtere = obj=>obj == null? null: obj.ToString().StartsWith("xyz");//return type is nullable cause of string
Expression<Func<object,bool>> filtere = obj=>Convert.ToInt32(obj) < 20 //return type is non-nullable cause of int
```

can someone plz guide me how to target this problem

Comment: It can be done; do you have an example of a source expression and what you'd want to convert it to?

Comment: no its first time i am trying to create one and have no idea where to start with

Comment: args is array of source lambdas of type `Expression<Func<T,object>>` and i want to convert them as written in second code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is that you're having, nor how the first and second parts of your question relate.

I can tell you that the ternary operator in your first expression will need to cast that `null` to `bool?`, so it will become:

```
Expression<Func<object,bool?>> filtere = obj=>obj == null
    ? (bool?)null 
    : obj.ToString().StartsWith("xyz");
```

Also, both expressions cannot share the same variable name of `filtere`.

Beyond that, you'll need to explain in somewhat more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Jay its not body of my method. its example of target expression that i want to achieve starting from `Expression<Func<T,object>>`. target is to create an expression of type `Expression<Func<object,bool?>>` if object is nullable and `Expression<Func<object,bool>>` otherwise.